# Importing a schema LDIF and content LDIF on every startup of ApacheDS?

Tags: java, schema, ldap, apacheds, ldif

I want my embedded ApacheDS to start up with a fresh schema/content when I run my tests. I tried to import a LDIF with this lines:

```
    LdifFileLoader ldifLoader = new LdifFileLoader(service.getAdminSession(), "path/to/my/export.ldif");
    ldifLoader.execute();
```

But now ApacheDS stores the information in a directory *server-work* in the current working directory. I had to manually delete the directory *server-work* every time and I wonder if that is the right way...

I exported the schema as LDIF too and I want to import it first. Can I import it with **LdifFileLoader** too? Or am I doing it in a wrong way at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use DirectoryService#setWorkingDirectory(File) to change the working directory.

In your setUp() or tearDown() methods, you can then delete this directory.

Answer (score 3):

Spring LDAP can be build a server on the fly for you and load it with an LDIF on startup.  The server it builds is an ApacheDS server.

```
 <security:ldap-server root="dc=example,dc=com" port="33389" ldif="classpath:EmbeddedServerRoot.ldif"/>
```